# javascript for loop creating too many tables

Tags: javascript, html, css

The script i made loops and creates a table(s) based on user input, if super=2 then there should be 2 tables outputed with different numbers in the tables its working pretty well, except that it is printing the first table as it should, then when it does the second one, it reprints the fist one also.. any ideas?

code:

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function createTable()
{
var num_ports = document.getElementById('ports').value;
var num_super = document.getElementById('super').value;
var num_rows = document.getElementById('rows').value;
var num_cols = document.getElementById('cols').value;
var tbody = '';
var colStart = num_cols / num_super;
var y = 1;
for( var i = 1; i <= num_super; i++){
    var theader = '<div style="margin:0 auto;"><table border="1" style="border:1px solid black; float:left;">\n';
        for(u = 1; u <= num_rows; u++){
          tbody += '<tr>';
            for( var j = 1; j <= colStart; j++)
            {
            tbody += '<td style="width:80px; height:70px;">';
            tbody += '<sub style="float:right; position:relative; top:24px; z-index:11;  ">' + y + '</sub>';
            tbody += '</td>';
            y++;
            }
    tbody += '</tr>\n';
}
var tfooter = '</table></div>';
document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML += theader + tbody + tfooter;
}
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="tablegen">
<label>Ports: <input type="text" name="ports" id="ports"/></label><br />
<label>Super Columns: <input type="text" name="super" id="super"/></label><br />
<label>Rows: <input type="text" name="rows" id="rows"/></label><br />
<label>Columns: <input type="text" name="cols" id="cols"/></label><br/>
<input name="generate" type="button" value="Create Table!" onclick='createTable();'/>
</form>

<div id="wrapper"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

what i should look like:

[image: should look like]

what it is looking like:

[image: bad table]

Comment: I'll give you a clue, you need to add `tbody = ''` somewhere....:)

Comment: @Liam Found it! Thanks for the hint man:P Sorry im not very good with javascript, still learning, but i supose from my background in php i should have caught that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the comment says - you clear tBody

```
var tbody = '';
```

before the loop , but that only happens once .  Since it is delclared outside the loop , and never reset to '' , the contents of the first table are still in there for the second loop , try

```
for( var i = 1; i <= num_super; i++){
    var tbody = '';
    //...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function createTable()
        {
            var num_ports = document.getElementById('ports').value;
            var num_super = document.getElementById('super').value;
            var num_rows = document.getElementById('rows').value;
            var num_cols = document.getElementById('cols').value;
            var tbody = '';
            var colStart = num_cols / num_super;
            var y = 1;
            for( var i = 1; i <= num_super; i++){
                var theader = '<div style="margin:0 auto;"><table border="1" style="border:1px solid black; float:left;">\n';
                tbody = '';
                for(u = 1; u <= num_rows; u++){
                    tbody += '<tr>';
                    for( var j = 1; j <= colStart; j++)
                    {
                        tbody += '<td style="width:80px; height:70px;">';
                        tbody += '<sub style="float:right; position:relative; top:24px; z-index:11;  ">' + y + '</sub>';
                        tbody += '</td>';
                        y++;
                    }
                    tbody += '</tr>\n';
                }
                var tfooter = '</table></div>';
                document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML += theader + tbody + tfooter;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="tablegen">
    <label>Ports: <input type="text" name="ports" id="ports"/></label><br />
    <label>Super Columns: <input type="text" name="super" id="super"/></label><br />
    <label>Rows: <input type="text" name="rows" id="rows"/></label><br />
    <label>Columns: <input type="text" name="cols" id="cols"/></label><br/>
    <input name="generate" type="button" value="Create Table!" onclick='createTable();'/>
</form>

<div id="wrapper"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

added `var tbody = '';`